# In a mysql database replace all dates with a specific date

Tags: mysql, database

I have a mysql database and I want to change the "modified" date with a specific date.

In the "modified column I have several dates: "2016-08-15" "2015-05-08" etc...
Now I want to change all these dates with an only date: "2021-12-31"

```
UPDATE jos_content SET modified = replace(modified, 'any date here', '2021-12-31’)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `UPDATE jos_content SET modified = '2021-12-31' WHERE modified IN ('2016-08-15', '2015-05-08')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you right this will set all the dates to 2021-12-31

```
UPDATE jos_content 
SET modified = '2021-12-31’
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE jos_content 
SET modified = '2021-12-31'
where modified in ('date1','date2'...)
```